# Flip sign of fixed point signal without using gain block Simulink

Tags: simulink, fixed-point

I have an incoming signal and I want to change it's sign. I can easily add a gain block (=-1) and flip the sign or multiply the signal by -1. However, I want to avoid this because the incoming signal is fixdt(1,24,39) which is very small. Consequently a gain block causes an overflow.

Is there a way I can manually flip the signed bit of the incoming signal instead?

Thanks :)

Comment: Multiplying a fixed-point value by -1 should never cause an overflow. I don't know simulink but something else is going on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I need to use a Unary Minus block:

https://au.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/unaryminus.html